# Unable to allow sudo access for jenkins for shell script

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, centos

I am trying to get jenkins to have a job that runs this command:

```
sudo -n sh /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

I have editied using visudo such that I added the following line on my CentOS machine:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
```

However when I run he job i still get:

```
Building on master in workspace /data/jenkins/Start_Sonar_Job/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8942100529506642093.sh
+ sudo -n sh /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
sudo: a password is required
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: related : http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Cmnd_Alias      CUSTOM_CMD=/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
jenkins        ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:CUSTOM_CMD
```